# What to plot when main effect significant but interaction insignificant?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, interaction, ggplot2, marginal-effect

This may be a silly question but:

Given a regression model that includes both main effects and an interaction term
(Score of participants predicted by their attitude and motivation):

```
model <- lm(Score ~ attitude + motivation + attitude:motivation)
```

According to the model summary, only `attitude` effects `behavior` signifcantly (*beta1 = 0.43*). Because of the included interaction term, the main effect cannot be interpreted independently: "For each increase in attitude, the score of a participant with no motivation increases by 0.43".

What should the corresponding plot look like?
Should it show the interaction, even though the term is insignificant?
3 possibilities: plot a single slope for the significant main effect (`Score~attitude`); combined plot for separate slopes for attitude and motivation(`Score~attitude;Score~motivation`), or simple slopes analysis plot/marginal effect for attitude at different levels of motivation (`Score~attitude:motivation`).

Answer (score 0):

Significance is not the issue. Interactions tend to be unreliable, which makes it harder to find significance; this is especially so when the main variables are measured unreliably, as they are here (variables such as attitude and motivation are always measured badly). And significance is related to sample size.

How big is the interaction effect?

Does the plot with the interaction look different than the one without?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - attitudes, motivation and behaviour are all likely very interlinked. There may be some multicollinearity issues with attitudes and motivation as predictor variables. Instead of (or alongside) your simple regression model, you could also present a correlation plot which will show the linear correlation between each pairwise combination of variables.

That way, you can see the correlation between attitudes and motivation, the correlation between attitudes and behaviour and the correlation between motivation and behaviour.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html